# how to access data structure from web API controller in .NET where the structure needs to be modified by the API controller

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What is the best practice for creating local data structure alongside Controller class for .NET core web API.

I have web API written in .NET which injects logger and Kafka producer:

```
public LoadTestController(ILogger<LoadTestController> logger,
             IEventBusProducer<string, string> producer)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _producer = producer;
            _messages = new Dictionary<int, Sample>();
        }
```

I need to use the dictionary to determine if a previous message of certain size was sent. However, for every POST request the constructor is called again for LoadTestController.

What is best practice to achieve that?

Is it best to inject that dictionary somehow (pass by reference from Startup and modify per request) ? or create new singelton service that owns this data structure?

Comment: well, the best practice, would of cause be the singleton service, serving as a sort of repository

Comment: @PatrickBeynio you need to be please a little more specific. thanks

Comment: is my new answer specific enough?

Comment: @PatrickBeynio I am reviewing your answer and about to take that approach. Thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the best practice, would be to add a singleton service, serving as a repository.

**[Singleton service registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-registration-methods)**

You can add a singleton service by either
providing a class

```cs
    services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();
```

or an instance

```cs
    services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService>(new SingletonService());
```

or an delegate

```cs
    services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService>(sp => new SingletonService());
```

wich go into `ConfigureServices`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other registrations

    services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();
    // or
    services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService>(new SingletonService());
    // or
    services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService>(sp => new SingletonService());
}
```

**[Design services for dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#design-services-for-dependency-injection)**

Best practices are to:

- Design services to use dependency injection to obtain their
  dependencies.
- Avoid stateful, static classes and members. Design apps
  to use singleton services instead, which avoid creating global state.
- Avoid direct instantiation of dependent classes within services.
- Direct instantiation couples the code to a particular implementation.
  Make app classes small, well-factored, and easily tested.

Also, in your case, you may want to guard your `Dictionary`, against concurrent requests, if the use of the service, is simple enough, a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) might serve you well.

If the service acts as an repository, it should at least have methods to set and get data. Otherwise, you might find a more advanced example of the repository pattern [here](https://codewithshadman.com/repository-pattern-csharp/)

**[Dependency injection into controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)**

You can simply inject services, by adding them as parameters, to the constructor

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ISingletonService _service;

    public MyController(ISingletonService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return Content( $"Current value: {_service.Get(111)}");
    }
}
```

or into actions using the [FromServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-injection-with-fromservices) attribute

```
public IActionResult About([FromServices] ISingletonService service)
{
    return Content( $"Current value: {service.Get(111)}");
}
```

**Minimal implementation**

Using best practice, you should give semantic value to your implementation, but keep in mind it's completely OK, to provide functionality by inheritance!
So if you really, only need the functionality of a `Dictionary`, a minimal service implementation for you, could look like this:

```cs
public interface IMessageRepository : IDictionary<int, Sample> { }

public class MessageRepository : ConcurrentDictionary<int, Sample>, IMessageRepository { }
```

Comment: thank you for the very detailed and organized answer :)